# why do I need to remove postmaster.pid?

Tags: postgresql, homebrew

I have postgres@15 installed via homebrew. Not every time, but regularly, I need to delete `/opt/homebrew/var/postgres@15/postmaster.pid` in order to access psql and boot my ruby app.

The error message is:

```
connexion to server on socket « /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432 » failed : No such file or directory (PG::ConnectionBad)
Is the server locally active and does it accept connexions on this socket?
```

After deletion of postmaster.pid, it work fine. No need to explicitly start the server.

This happens whether I explicitly do or do not stop the server when I turn off the computer.

Not a big issue, but still: is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: 1) Deleting `postmaster.pid` when the server is still running would not be good. Do you confirm the Postgres is not running? 2) If it is not running then whatever method is being used to shut down the server is not cleaning up properly. How is the server being shut down? **Add answers as update to question**.

Comment: Shut down PostgreSQL cleanly instead of crashing the server.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe : do you explicitly run `brew services stop postgres@15`before turning your computer off?

Comment: I don't have MacOS. But if the PID file stays behind, it is a sign that the server crashed. You can either explicitly shot down PostgreSQL or modify your operating system shutdown procedure so that it does that automatically.

Comment: thanks. It's a bit strange that services installed with homebrew need to be shut down explicitly. When I stop postgres explicitly before turning off the computer, the postmaster.pid file is not deleted. By the way, you probably meant `shut down`, not `shot down`.